# converting into XML

Tags: xml, regex

I am trying to convert a conversation I downloaded from Wikipedia into XML. I used the special export to get the page in XML format... that works great until I get to the main conversation.

```
<conversation>
    {{PersonA|Cheese}}
    {{PersonB|I like it too...}}
    {{PersonA|Cheese?}}
</conversation>
```

Thats not the real conversation... anyway, I'm wondering whats the easiest way to convert a MASSIVE conversation like that into valid XML?

```
<conversation>
    <personA>Cheese</personA>
    <personB>I like it too...</personB>
    <personA>Cheese?</personA>
</conversation>
```

Thanks, this is far too long to do it manually. I'm guessing regex can help out... somehow.

Comment: Does every line start with either `{{PersonA|` or `{{PersonB|`?

Comment: yep. they all seem to start like that... the only other exception is {{Action|

Answer (score 2):

Pattern:

```
\{\{(.*?)\|(.*?)\}\}
```

Replace:

```
<$1>$2</$1>
```

This is a simple solution that will fit your sample, but depending on the exact format, a more complex expression may be needed. E.g., what if a name contains a pipe? What if the text contains two closing curly brackets? Can text span multiple lines?

Comment: Thanks Max, I'll try that out... So will I need a special text editor to perform that action? Also, how are the $1 and $2 variables defined?

Comment: You need a text editor that supports regular expressions. I suppose most of them do by now, but you will have to tell the search/replace command to use them. `$1` (often also written `\1`) is a backreference, containing what was matched in the first set of parentheses.